# Append attribute to each element in XML File

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an xml and I want to append an attribute to each element in xml file.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> childList = from el in xml.Elements()
                                  select el;

textBox1.Text = childList.ToString();

foreach (XElement el in childList)
{
    el.Add(new XAttribute("Liczba_Potomkow", "dziesiec"));
    textBox1.Text = el.ToString();
    xml.Save("Employees.xml");
}
```

unfortunately, when I open the file only the first line seems to be affected. (only first elements gets new attribute). Why is so ?

Comment: And what should I modify so that the value of each attribute was the number of nodes (not only children) ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume `xml` is an `XDocument`? If so, you're calling `Elements()` directly on the *parent* of the root element - so the only element it finds will be the root element itself.

If you want to do something for *all* elements in the document, you should use the [`Descendants()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants.aspx) method.

Additionally, your query expression is pointless - you might as well just use `xml.Elements()` - and I really don't think you should be saving in a loop.

I think you just want:

```
foreach (var element in xml.Descendants())
{
    element.Add(new XAttribute("Liczba_Potomkow", "dziesiec"));
}
xml.Save("Employees.xml");
```

Comment: And what should I modify so that the value of each attribute was the number of nodes (not only children, of course different for each element) ? – Peter 2 mins ago edit

Comment: Found answer myself!
var ile = element.Descendants().Count();

Comment: @Peter: It's not really clear what you mean, to be honest. Perhaps ask that as a separate question. Bear in mind that "node" can mean different things to different APIs. Would you include attributes as nodes? (The old DOM API does, but LINQ to XML doesn't.) Note that `Descendants()` only finds *elements* - so it doesn't include text nodes.